# How to create Array Variable of Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

https://medium.com/tech-start/looping-a-task-in-azure-devops-ac07a68a5556

Below is my Main Pipeline:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

parameters:
- name: environment
displayName: 'Select Environment To Deploy'
type: string
values:
  - A1
  - A2
default: A1

variables:
- name: abc
 value: 'firm20 firm201' # How to declare Array variable?

 stages:
 - stage: stage01
   displayName: 'Deploy in Environment '
   jobs:
   - template: templates/test_task_for.yml  # Template reference
#      parameters:
#        list: $(abc)
```

Now is my template pipeline below:

```
parameters:
- name: list
  type: ??? #What type here pls?
  default: []  #? is this correct?

jobs:
- job: connectxyz
  displayName: 'Connect'
  steps: 
  - ${{each mc in variables.abc}}:  # parameters.list
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: 'echo Write your commands here. ${{mc}}'
```

I need to run CmdLine@2 task multiple times

How to define values in Main Pipeline abc  so that it can be passed as parameter to Template file?

What datatype of Parameter so it can work as array?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Pipelines does not have an array parameter type. You can use an `object` type and iterate over it.

User-defined variables are **not typed**. A variable is a string, period. You cannot define a variable containing an array of items.

However, you could add a delimited list, then `split` the list.

i.e.

```
variables:
  foo: a,b,c,d

- ${{ each x in split(variables.foo, ',') }}:
  - script: echo ${{ x }}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. When i tested it does not print x value.